# How to get last modified file in a directory to pass to system commands using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do some dev-ops. I need to grab the last modified file in a directory to pass the filename to another command.

If I had a list of files outputted with `ls -la` in Ruby:

```
-rw-r--r--  1  163929215 2012-11-26 00:02 appname_20121126_000002.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164051752 2012-11-27 00:02 appname_20121127_000002.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164160113 2012-11-28 00:02 appname_20121128_000002.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164284597 2012-11-29 00:02 appname_20121129_000004.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164342795 2012-11-30 00:02 appname_20121130_000003.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164448312 2012-12-01 00:02 appname_20121201_000003.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164490727 2012-12-02 00:02 appname_20121202_000002.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164546124 2012-12-03 00:02 appname_20121203_000001.tgz
-rw-r--r--  1  164594711 2012-12-04 00:02 appname_20121204_000002.tgz
```

How could I scan this with Ruby and pull the last file?

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: It's very possible and there are multiple ways to do it. It's also something that is covered many times on SO. `String.split` will be useful to you, as will `Enumerable.sort` and `DateTime.parse`. You might want to look at `ls -alrt` also.

Comment: You could avoid shelling out to `ls` by using ruby's stdlib. [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and [`File::mtime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-mtime) give you what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to shell out to `ls` and parse its output at all. Ruby gives you standard library methods to fetch directory contents and examine file mtimes. Here's a ruby method to return the name of a file in a directory with the latest mtime.

```
def last_modified_in dir
  Dir.glob( File.join( dir,'*' ) ).
  select  {|f| File.file? f }.
  sort_by {|f| File.mtime f }.
  last
end

irb> system 'mkdir -p /tmp/foo'
irb> system 'rm /tmp/foo/*'
irb> ('a'..'c').each { |f| system "touch /tmp/foo/#{f}"; sleep 1; }
irb> puts last_modified_in '/tmp/foo'
# => /tmp/foo/c
```

Comment: Thank you. Absolutely what I needed.